# No respond from getSelectedItem Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Spinner with list of category, which get the data from JSON. I want to make, when an item other than *All Category* get selected, another spinner of subcategory become visible, and get loaded with data from JSON according to its category.

Previously I managed to do it but after left it for a few days and have other parts done, it no longer works.

Since the first one loaded into spinner is *All Category*, it triggered `setOnItemSelectedListener()` and hid `subcategorySpinner`. If other item get selected, `subcategorySpinner` still not shown.

Is there something wrong with the code logic? Please help.

```
categorySpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categorySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, categoryList);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
categorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);

categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
categoryString = categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().replace(" ", "%20");
if (categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("All Category")) {
   Log.d("debug", "all category");
   subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   Log.d("debug", "other than all category");
   subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   generateSubcategorySpinner(Config.GET_SUBCATEGORY_URL+"?category="+categoryString);
}
}


});
```

Comment: @HRaval you mean, comment it out?

Comment: @SathishKumarJ I only get Log of "all category"

Comment: first check What you get from `Spinner` like `String str = spinnerName.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: use categorySpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(position) instead of getSelectedItem()

Comment: @SathishKumarJ in log, got All Category

Comment: @HRaval the items have no Id assigned, as it is from Array

Comment: array also have position...its basic java rule...and here i am not using array...get spinner item by its position...you can get position inside your onItemSelected()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't quite get what I have done logically because it seems nothing much different but this solved it. Oh well.. whatever floats the boat, I guess.

Using suggestion by H Raval, I moved the `if else` into a method and now it works just like I wanted.

```
categorySpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categorySpinner);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, categoryList);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
                categorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
                String str = categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.d("debug", "str "+str);

                categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        categoryString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Log.d("debug", categoryString+"..."+position);

                        subCategorySpinnerView(categoryString);
                    }
                });

private void subCategorySpinnerView(String categoryString) {

    if (categoryString.equals("All Category")) {
        Log.d("debug", "all category");
        subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        Log.d("debug", "other than all category");
        subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        categoryString = categoryString.replace(" ", "%20");
        generateSubcategorySpinner(Config.GET_SUBCATEGORY_URL+"?category="+categoryString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


// On selecting a spinner item
categoryString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Log.d("debug", categoryString+"..."+position);

if (categoryString.equals("All Category")) {
   Log.d("debug", "all category");
   subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   Log.d("debug", "other than all category");
   subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   categoryString = categoryString.replace(" ", "%20")
   generateSubcategorySpinner(Config.GET_SUBCATEGORY_URL+"?category="+categoryString);
}
}
```

Comment: still the same. it as if, the `if else` didn't run again after the item got selected (didn't get the Log in `else`)

Comment: please run above code and tell me what do you get in log after changing selection

Comment: the output still same

Comment: i am asking for log...not for output which item and position you are getting in log...please post it

Comment: `All Category...0`, `all category`

Comment: do you get same output all the time? also when you switch to next item? pz post your array

Comment: Array `categoryList`: `[All Category, Arts and Entertainment, Business and Finance, Computers, Health, Home, News, People, Recreation, Schools and Universities, Science and Technology, Society, Adult]`

Comment: and all time position is 0...even position is not changing

Comment: `All Category...0` only printed once (when `categoryList` get loaded into spinner). when other item get selected, `setOnItemSelectedListener` not triggered again. err... did you get what I mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125681/discussion-between-h-raval-and-august).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
Spinner dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.type);
final String[] items = new String[]{"SELECT TYPE OF OFFER","PERCENTAGE", "AMOUNT", "ITEM"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item, items);
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
String selectedItem = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


// On selecting a spinner item
         categoryString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().replace(" ", "%20");



if (categoryString.equals("All Category")) {
   Log.d("debug", "all category");
   subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   Log.d("debug", "other than all category");
   subcategorySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   generateSubcategorySpinner(Config.GET_SUBCATEGORY_URL+"?category="+categoryString);
}
}
```

Comment: the output still same

Answer (score 0):

You can direcly use the, argument(position)

Instead of,
categoryString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

You can use like,
categoryString = position.toString();